# Google Action with SSML rejected for "having HTML tags"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai, ssml

I submitted my first Action on Google last week.

I have written the code using Dialogflow and WebhookClient, and targeted 2 languages - English and Hindi.

My Action was approved for English, but got back a "denied" status for Hindi with the review "ऐप प्रतिक्रियाओं में एचटीएमएल टैग हैं |" ("App responses have HTML tags")

I have 2 related questions regarding this review -

1. I am using ssml that I learnt from the following reference material -

   - https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml
   - https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

And it seems, I am exactly following the documents.

My code looks something like this -

```
function repeatWord(agent) {
    let sessionContext = agent.getContext(KEY_SESSION);
    let sessionParams = sessionContext.parameters;

    let currentWord = 
              sessionParams.words[sessionParams.currentIndexPosition];
    let ssml;

    if(sessionParams.userLang === 'hi'){
        ssml = `<speak>\n ठीक है। शब्द <sub alias = 
              '${currentWord[KEY_PRONOUNCE]}'>${currentWord[KEY_WORD]} 
              </sub> है।
              <break time='500ms'/>\n  हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा 
              ${currentWord[KEY_MEANING]} । </speak>` ;
        agent.add(new Suggestion('अगला शब्द'));
        agent.add(new Suggestion('दोहराना'));
     } else {
        ssml = `<speak>\n Ok! Let's do this again.
                \n The word is <sub alias = 
              '${currentWord[KEY_PRONOUNCE]}'>${currentWord[KEY_WORD]} 
               .</sub>
              <break time='500ms'/>\n In English, it would mean 
              ${currentWord[KEY_MEANING]} .</speak>` ;
        agent.add(new Suggestion('next word'));
        agent.add(new Suggestion('repeat'));
     }
     agent.add(ssml);
   }
```

Is this the right way to do it?

2. The example given in review with the rejection is below. But, the example response is the one that was used in Version 1 -

   ```
   <speak><p><s>ठीक है। शब्द <sub alias='sthaalikaa'>स्थालिका </sub> है।</s> <s> हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा थाली ।</s></p></speak> <speak><p><s> हमारा पहला शब्द आज <sub alias='sthaalikaa'>स्थालिका </sub> है।</s> <s> हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा थाली । </s></p></speak>
   ```

My new response in Version 2 looks like this -

```
<speak>\n ठीक है। शब्द <sub alias='adhyaapikaa'>अध्यापिका </sub> है।\n      <break time='500ms'/>\n  हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा शिक्षक (महिला) । </speak>
```

Is it possible that my Version 1 is getting resubmitted for review? How do I update the version for review? It is working as updated in the simulator.

The Response in simulator is logged as -

```
{

  "conversationToken": "[\"learn\",\"select-track\",\"session_vars\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": " ",
                "displayText": " "
              }
            },
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "<speak>\n ठीक है। शब्द <sub alias='vaatikaa'>वाटिका </sub> है।\n      <break time='500ms'/>\n  हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा वाटिका । </speak>",
                "displayText": "<speak>\n ठीक है। शब्द <sub alias='vaatikaa'>वाटिका </sub> है।\n      <break time='500ms'/>\n  हिंदी में, इसका मतलब होगा वाटिका । </speak>"
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "अगला शब्द"
            },
            {
              "title": "दोहराना"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        },
        {
          "intent": "9c81a50f-4016-42f1-af46-43c5935cfd7a"
        },
        {
          "intent": "720a2df8-c900-43bb-a2bd-bc42ced8661e"
        },
        {
          "intent": "6e209797-e4f1-43aa-bbe6-3ee36bd3b416"
        },
        {
          "intent": "c5b09a55-3b1e-47c8-9500-508adaf5fe87"
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$answer",
        "$track"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "6e209797-e4f1-43aa-bbe6-3ee36bd3b416"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is odd in the way the `displayText` is generated from the SSML you're providing. Typically, this should be handled behind the scenes for you, but it sounds like it isn't in this case - possibly because of the character set being used?

You can work around this by explicitly setting the SSML and the text yourself. So instead of the `agent.add(ssml)` line, you might build a `text` variable that contains just the text of what you want shown and add it with something like

```
agent.add(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: ssml,
  text:   text
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked. My action is now approved.

The only thing is I was getting a server error in my code when using agent.add

So, I added new SimpleResponse as - 

conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({ speech: ssml,
                                  text: text}));
agent.add(conv);